# Calculate PageRank for small web

Tags: algorithms, data-mining, page-rank

> Calculate PageRank for: A links to B, B links to C and C links to B and C where the damping factor $\beta=0.8$

I have:

$M=\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&\frac{1}{2} \\
1&0&\frac{1}{2} \\
0&1&0
\end{bmatrix}$

and

$v=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{3} \\ \frac{1}{3}  \\ \frac{1}{3}  
\end{bmatrix}$

So we get $(1-\beta)\frac{e}{n}=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{15} \\ \frac{1}{15}  \\ \frac{1}{15}  
\end{bmatrix}$

and $\beta M = \begin{bmatrix}
0&0&\frac{1}{30} \\
\frac{1}{15}&0&\frac{1}{30} \\
0&\frac{1}{15}&0
\end{bmatrix}$

And therefore we get $$ v' =\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{15} \\ \frac{1}{15}  \\ \frac{1}{15}  
\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&\frac{1}{30} \\
\frac{1}{15}&0&\frac{1}{30} \\
0&\frac{1}{15}&0
\end{bmatrix} v $$

Is this correct?